# Laravel is not show exceptions in browser suddenly stop displaying errors( fatal errors,warnings, etc)?

Tags: laravel, exception

Application was working fine before some days suddenly I am getting this error on any exception in app like syntax or any other type of error but showing n Apache error.log file. I have also implemented all solution which i have found  but no luck yet.
Using ,Laravel =  v5.4

Thanks and looking for your prompt response.

[check error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tua6K.png)

Comment: And what is the error in you Apache error log?

Comment: go to `htdocs/pt` and run `php artisan serve` to start `localhost:8000` and try

Comment: Apache error log is showing , which should be show with whoops something wrong with stack traces

Answer (score 1):

Check your [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php) and check the following

```
display_errors = on
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

Also check your laravel .env file and turn debug mode on

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```

Comment: Also check the `APP_ENV` value in your .env. It has to be `local`. When it is production, all error-messages are not visible.

Comment: all above changes which you provided have been implemented

Comment: i can send you .env file if you want .

Comment: APP_NAME=APP.NAME
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:EIPiIzBtRzN7zciGyOYwS6xsTbhQs+LUjmxQfZs5we0=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=database.name
DB_USERNAME=user.name
DB_PASSWORD=
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=array
SESSION_DRIVER=database
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

Comment: Don't show it here, it's unsecure. Your .env seem to be OK, after changing php.ini configuration you need to restart apache as well.

Comment: Apache restarted 3-4 times but no luck.

Comment: create new file called info.php and put <?php phpinfo(); ?> line there, try to visit it in browser, it should print you php settings, try to find display_errors & error_reporting settings and double check them if they are correctly set. Or just in your public/index.php call phpinfo(); on first line.

Comment: it's numeric representation of E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED, try to change error_reporting to E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & E_STRICT and restart apache

Comment: it has been written PHP.ini and strange thing is that this problem is only happening in my laravel 5.4 application.